# How can I install third-party packages in the console?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'd like to ask you how can I install tesseract-ocr package without `sudo` ? My app will be using this package but how can I install it without access to `sudo` in the console ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which system image you have on PythonAnywhere, you should already have tesseract installed. See [this](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/) to check.